# Get census block ID from GIS file using st_join in r

Tags: r, gis

I am working with two datasets in R: a list of addresses with latitude and longitude values, and a GIS file representing the boundaries of census blocks in South Korea.

The GIS file contains codes for each census block (TOT_REG_CD) along with other information. The file is named census_id.shp and looks like this:

```
> census_BL_boundary
Simple feature collection with 104292 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 746111 ymin: 1458603 xmax: 1387949 ymax: 2068444
Projected CRS: KGD2002 / Unified CS
First 10 features:
   BASE_DATE   ADM_CD     TOT_REG_CD                       geometry
1   20220630 29010110 29010110010001 MULTIPOLYGON (((982172 1846...
2   20220630 29010110 29010110010101 MULTIPOLYGON (((981831.7 18...
3   20220630 29010110 29010110020003 MULTIPOLYGON (((982701 1844...
4   20220630 29010110 29010110020002 MULTIPOLYGON (((982185.9 18...
5   20220630 29010110 29010110020001 MULTIPOLYGON (((982448.6 18...
6   20220630 29010110 29010110020007 MULTIPOLYGON (((982521.4 18...
7   20220630 29010110 29010110020006 MULTIPOLYGON (((982254 1845...
8   20220630 29010110 29010110020005 MULTIPOLYGON (((982027.1 18...
9   20220630 29010110 29010110020004 MULTIPOLYGON (((982666.7 18...
10  20220630 29010110 29010110020009 MULTIPOLYGON (((981869.9 18...
```

The other file contains a long list of addresses with their respective latitude and longitude. It looks something like this:

```
   > head(add)
           lon      lat
    1 126.9904 37.57180
    2 127.0153 37.57254
    3 126.9860 37.56995
    4 126.9670 37.56739
    5 126.9710 37.57226
    6 126.9729 37.57483
```

My goal is to append the TOT_REG_CD and related information from the GIS file to the address data based on their latitude and longitude.

Here is the code I have attempted:

```
library(sf)
add
head(add)

census_BL_boundary <- st_read("census_id.shp")
census_BL_boundary

add_sf <- st_as_sf(add, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = st_crs(census_BL_boundary))
joined_data <- st_join(add_sf, census_BL_boundary)
```

I'm encountering an issue where the joined data (joined_data) only shows NA values.
What I have obtained from the above codes is:

```
> joined_data
Simple feature collection with 2025 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 126.5687 ymin: 36.98421 xmax: 127.7803 ymax: 38.09119
Projected CRS: KGD2002 / Unified CS
First 10 features:
   BASE_DATE ADM_CD TOT_REG_CD                  geometry
1       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>  POINT (126.9904 37.5718)
2       <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (127.0153 37.57254)
3       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>  POINT (126.986 37.56995)
4       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>  POINT (126.967 37.56739)
5       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>  POINT (126.971 37.57226)
6       <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (126.9729 37.57483)
7       <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (126.9829 37.58806)
8       <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (126.9692 37.60682)
9       <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (127.0203 37.57404)
10      <NA>   <NA>       <NA> POINT (126.9988 37.57916)
```

Any help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`crs` argument of `st_as_sf()` does not transform but defines the coordinate reference system of your input, lon/lat columns of `add`, but those values are most likely geographic coordinates (WGS84) and definitely not projected KGD2002.

Try importing your points first using `WGS84` and only then transform to target crs:

```r
add_sf <- 
  st_as_sf(add, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_transform(crs = st_crs(census_BL_boundary))
joined_data <- st_join(add_sf, census_BL_boundary)
```