# How to assgin a point to a geographic region

Tags: r, gis

I have got a panel dataset with geolocated individuals in Africa. I would like to know which region (level ADM2) corresponds to each coordinate.

I've tried to import the shapefile of Benin for example, that allowed me to get the regions' polygons. I have in mind that I have to create region indexes, and then run a code that means "If the coordinates of the individual are within the borders of one polygon, thus this individual is part of this polygon (region)".

```
panel_sf %<>%
  filter(cname=="Benin")

regions <- st_read("G:/Mon Drive/Working paper/Trust/Script/Data/Data_Raw/gadm41_BEN_2.shp")

regions_valid <- st_make_valid(regions)

panel_sf <- st_as_sf(panel_sf, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = st_crs(regions_valid))

panel_with_regions <- st_join(panel_sf, regions_valid)
```

But there is no difference between panel_sf and panel_with_regions.

Comment: Perhaps you are wanting `st_intersects(panel_sf, regions_valid)`? This will tell you exactly which points are within which region.

Comment: Is (the orginal) `panel_sf` an `sf` object as the name suggests?  If the idea behind `st_as_sf(panel_sf, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = st_crs(regions_valid))` is to transform it to the same projection as `regions_valid`, I' m afraid it will not work like this, for transformation from one coordinate system to another there's `st_transform()` , Somehow this question seems oddly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77784794/get-census-block-id-from-gis-file-using-st-join-in-r - different datasets but identical tags and similar approach, asked few hours appart.